# how to improve my draw for I2C bus

Tags: beamer, circuitikz, tikz-timing

I already created a I2C bus block diagram with line and device (but I think my method is very poor...I checked on web and did not found any example for I2C protocol draw by latex):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{I$^{2}$C}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (11,3);
%    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,11}
%           \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
%    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
%       \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

    %draw master and slave device
    \draw [rounded corners, fill=blue!30] (0, 1.5) rectangle (2.5,3) node[pos=.5] {I$^{2}$C Master};
    \foreach \x in {3,6,9}
    {
        \draw [rounded corners, fill=orange] (\x, 0) rectangle (\x+2,1) node[pos=.5] {I$^{2}$C Slave};
    }

    %draw circuit
    \draw[very thick] (2.5,1.8) -- (11,1.8) node[pos=1, below] {$SCL$};    %SCL
    \draw[very thick] (2.5,2.7) -- (11,2.7) node[pos=1, above] {$SDA$};    %SDA
    \foreach \x in {3.5, 6.5, 9.5}
    {
        \draw (\x, 1) -- (\x, 1.8);
        \node at (\x, 1.8) {\textbullet};
    }
    \foreach \x in {4.5, 7.5, 10.5}
    {
        \draw (\x, 1) -- (\x, 2.7);
        \node at (\x, 2.7) {\textbullet};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if there is any package to draw I2C? My idea is to always draw a net:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (11,3);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,11}
            \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And start my draw in this net.

Can anyone help me to optimize my code and to draw this I2C bus and device easily?

In addition, I want to have a follow I2C protocol draw, can anyone give me a start point?

[image]

or this one seems easy?

[image]

Comment: [`tikz-timing`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing)

Comment: @Ignasi, I checked `tikz-timing` and trying now, could you give me a start point? timing I think should be easy but how to add text? meanwhile, any idea to easy draw the `I2C` block circuit? if my way is OK?

Comment: I've only used it two or three times and always start from a manual's given example and modify it step to step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a grid as refernce, you can use already drawn `nodes` as reference with `positioning` library help.

Instead of `rectangles`+`text` use `drawn` and `filled` nodes.

Finally, use nodes anchors and intersection coordinates to position or define other elements.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}[fragile]{I\textsuperscript{2}C}
\begin{tikzpicture}[master/.style={draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30, minimum height=15mm, minimum width=2.5cm},
slave/.style={draw, rounded corners, fill=orange, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=2cm}]

    \node[master] (m) {I\textsuperscript{2}C Master};
    \node[slave, below right=3mm and 7mm of m] (s1) {I\textsuperscript{2}C Slave};
    \node[slave, right= 6mm of s1] (s2) {I\textsuperscript{2}C Slave};
    \node[slave, right= 6mm of s2] (s3) {I\textsuperscript{2}C Slave};

    \draw[thick] (m.15)--(m.15-|s3.east) node[above]{SDA};
    \draw[thick] (m.-15)--(m.-15-|s3.east)node[below]{SCL};
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
        \draw[fill=black] (s\i.55)--(s\i.55|-m.15) circle (2pt);
        \draw[fill=black] (s\i.115)--(s\i.115|-m.-15) circle (2pt);
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]